# CreateProcessA without sharing symbols

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, process

I'm using CreateProcessA function to create another process (exe). However, the child process seem to use the dlls and symbols loaded by the parent process.
Is there a way to create a process independently, so it won't use its parent symbols?

Comment: What do you mean by "symbols" here? Environment variables? What do you mean by "use the DLLs"? What specific problem do you observe?

Comment: ***the child process seem to use the dlls and symbols loaded by the parent process*** I think you are discussing a feature of your debugger. Processes don't use symbols your debugger does.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I encounter inconsistency of dll usage (dlls loaded by a process) when running my exe independently (double click for example), against running the same process using CreateProcess. So as a child process it loads the wrong dll. Probably because both dlls are similar and consist the same symbols (methods).

Comment: @TomerS. Parent and child processes don’t share DLLs. But they can share environments and working directories, which may affect how the child loads DLLs for itself.

Comment: Maybe its a path problem. In that starting from CreateProcess you inherit the environment of the parent process.

Comment: Put all the DLLs in the same directory as the exe, or use a SxS manifest, and take control over how dependencies are resolved.